# GSON failing to deserialize JSON with nested array of objects?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have a pretty standard use-case here:

```
{
  "title": "my awesome title",
  "description": "all the awesome things",
  "theThings": [
    {
      "thing": "coolThing1",
      "association-type": "thing"
    },
    {
      "thing": "coolThing2",
       "association-type": "thing"
      }

  ]
}
```

I'm utilizing the following class structure to use with GSON:

```
package things;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ThingsPOJO implements Serializable
{
  @SerializedName("title")
  @Expose
  public String title = "";

  @SerializedName("description")
  @Expose
  public String description = "";

  @SerializedName("theThings")
  @Expose
  public List<TheThing> theThings = null;

  private class TheThing implements Serializable
  {

    @SerializedName("thing")
    @Expose
    public String thing = "";

    @SerializedName("association-type")
    @Expose
    public String associationType = "";

  }

}
```

title and description are good to go, but the collection of objects is null. I'm testing using that example payload from above. I'm using the `fromJson` call provided by GSON.

Comment: You don't need `@SerializedName` and `@Expose` on everything, unless you specified that you do via the `GsonBuilder`

Comment: Have you tried initializing `theThings` field with a default, empty list value? Like `public List<TheThing> theThings = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: also, try not to mix `camelCase` with `dashy-case`. Choose one and be consistent (:

Comment: I haven't I will try this. Class was auto generated, which explains the annotations.

Comment: what was it generated with?

Comment: Json to pojo web app online. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @Jezor darn, just an array list with size 0 when I initialize it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171848/discussion-between-ryan-hack-and-jezor).